# Why is this model's association disappearing from the test once the assertion is made (after a rails 5.1 > 5.2 upgrade)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a model in this application that tracks role changes. The test I'm about to describe has been passing for the last couple years no problem and only starting failing as I upgraded the rails version from 5.1 to 5.2.

Here's an excerpt from the model:

```
class RoleChange < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :actor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'actor_id'
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'subject_id'
  validates :subject_id, presence: true

  def subject
    User.with_deleted.find(subject_id)
  end

  ...
end
```

And the assertion that is failing in the spec is the following

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RoleChange, type: :model do
  let(:organization) { create(:organization) }
  let(:admin) { organization.users.admins.first }
  let!(:user) { create(:employee_user, organization: organization) }
  subject { create(:role_change, subject: user, actor: admin) }

  describe 'associations' do
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:actor) }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:subject) }
  end

  ...

end
```

The second association assertion fails with the following error:

```
  1) RoleChange associations is expected to belong to subject required:
     Failure/Error: User.with_deleted.find(subject_id)

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User without an ID
     # ./app/models/role_change.rb:28:in `subject'
```

This is very frustrating.

When I `binding.pry` inside of an `it` block, the subject appears to be `valid?` and `persisted?` with a `subject_id` as you'd expect.

It's only once I run the assertion, the `subject_id` magically becomes `nil`.

For additional context, my adventures in the rails console:

[image: The subject is there!]

when I run the assertion, it fails and says that nil can’t be found:

[image: Schrodinger's foreign key]

Totally baffling. Can you help me finish this rails upgrade? It's my last failing test.

UPDATE:

deleting the `subject` getter method from `RoleChange` makes the test pass but then I lose the benefit of including deleted users from the query. So... doesn't actually seem like a solution.

Comment: use a default scope if that's what you're trying to do, having 2 methods both named `subject` is a smell.

Comment: I need the deleted users to be included in the query (using acts_as_paranoid)

Comment: IMO, your issue is likely due to the wonkiness in how that class is defined; you're defining a method that conflicts with a model association (that also appears redundant to the association). Remove the `subject` method entirely; its goal is to find the associated object, and rails already takes care of that. Also change your validation to `validates :subject, presence: true`.

Comment: OK, then how do I get the subject query on the model to include deleted users? See the comment above.